# Append States to Countries from API Data

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an API that is returning data in the following format:

```
[
 {
  "id": 12,
  "acf": {
    "address": {
      "city": "Bandar Penawar",
      "state": "Johor",
      "country": "Malaysia",
   }
 },
 {
  "id": 16,
  "acf": {
    "address": {
      "city": "Some City",
      "state": "Arizona",
      "country": "United States",
   }
 }
]
```

Right now, I'm getting the list of countries and states with the following computed code:

```
computed: {
    countries() {
      const countries = new Set();
      this.$store.state.posts.forEach((post) =>
        countries.add(post.acf.address.country)
      );
      return Array.from(countries);
    },
    states() {
      const states = new Set();
      this.$store.state.posts.forEach((post) =>
        states.add(post.acf.address.state)
      );
      return Array.from(states);
    },
  },
```

This returns two separate arrays, `countries` and `states`, how can I organize the array by country, then states within that country?

Comment: What format do you want the data in?

Comment: So far, it appears a nested array would work perfectly! I can't figure out how to append the corresponding states with their countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary whose key is the country name and value is an array of states:

```js
computed: {
  dictionary() {
    const dictionary = {};
    this.$store.state.posts.forEach(post => {
      const c = post.acf.address.country;
      const s = post.acf.address.state;
      dictionary[c] = dictionary[c] || [];
      !dictionary[c].includes(s) && dictionary[c].push(s);
    });
    return dictionary;
  }
}
```

Handling duplicates:  If the `&&`/`push` statement looks strange, it's like a short `if` statement testing whether the state is in the list already, and only reaches the push statement if not

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, this is easily the best way to do what you asked.  Nested state arrays, and you can `v-for` it for both country and state names.